# ERROR: no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «competencia»

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
            -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                    TABLA LOG_ERROR                 --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log_error (
  id_error SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre_error VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  fecha TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
  
              -- -----------------------------------------------------
              --                    TABLA SERVIDOR_CORREO            --
              -- -----------------------------------------------------
  
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS servidor_correo (
  id_servidor SERIAL,
  nombre_servidor VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_servidor));
  
              -- -----------------------------------------------------
              --                         TABLA ROL                  --
              -- -----------------------------------------------------
  
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rol (
  id_rol  SERIAL,
  nombre_rol VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_rol));
  
              -- -----------------------------------------------------
              --                            TABLA RH                --
              -- -----------------------------------------------------
  
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rh (
  id_rh  SERIAL,
  nombre_rh VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_rh));
  
              -- -----------------------------------------------------
              --                    TABLA TIPO_DOCUMENTO            --
              -- -----------------------------------------------------
  
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tipo_documento (
  id_tipo_documento  SERIAL,
  siglas_documento VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  nombre_tipo_documento VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_tipo_documento));
  
              -- -----------------------------------------------------
              --                       TABLA USUARIO                --
              -- -----------------------------------------------------
  
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario (
  numero_documento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  primer_nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  segundo_nombre VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  primer_apellido VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  segundo_apellido VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  correo_electronico VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  foto BYTEA NOT NULL DEFAULT 'https://miro.medium.com/max/720/1*W35QUSvGpcLuxPo3SRTH4w.png',
  telefono_usuario VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  edad_usuario INT NOT NULL,
  contrasena VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_rh INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_rol INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (numero_documento, fk_id_tipo_documento),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento)
    REFERENCES tipo_documento (id_tipo_documento),

    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_rh)
    REFERENCES rh (id_rh),

    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_rol)
    REFERENCES rol (id_rol));
  CREATE INDEX fk_id_tipoDocumento_index ON usuario(fk_id_tipo_documento);
  CREATE INDEX fk_id_rh_index ON usuario(fk_id_rh ASC);
  CREATE INDEX fk_id_rol_index ON usuario(fk_id_rol ASC);
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mail_index ON usuario(correo_electronico);
    
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                 TABLA OPINION                      --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS opinion (
  id_opinion SERIAL,
  fecha_opinion TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  titulo_opinion VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  opinion_texto TEXT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  fk_numero_documento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_opinion, fk_id_tipo_documento, fk_numero_documento),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento)
    REFERENCES usuario (fk_id_tipo_documento , numero_documento));
    CREATE INDEX fk_id_tipo_documento_index ON opinion(fk_id_tipo_documento ASC, fk_numero_documento ASC);
  
  
            -- -----------------------------------------------------
            --                 TABLA ADMINISTRADOR                --
            -- -----------------------------------------------------
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS administrador (
  fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  fk_numero_documento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento, fk_numero_documento),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento)
    REFERENCES usuario (fk_id_tipo_documento , numero_documento));
    CREATE INDEX fk_id_documento_tipo_numer_index ON administrador(fk_id_tipo_documento ASC, fk_numero_documento ASC);
    
    
            -- -----------------------------------------------------
            --                 TABLA APRENDIZ                     --
            -- -----------------------------------------------------
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aprendiz (
  fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  fk_numero_documento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento, fk_numero_documento),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento)
    REFERENCES usuario (fk_id_tipo_documento , numero_documento));
    CREATE INDEX fk_id_documento_tipo_numero_index ON aprendiz(fk_id_tipo_documento ASC, fk_numero_documento ASC);
  
  
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                 TABLA VINCULACIÓN                  --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vinculacion (
  id_vinculacion SERIAL,
  nombre_vinculacion VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  horas_de_trabajo INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_vinculacion));
  

             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                 TABLA ESPECIALIDAD                 --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS especialidad (
  id_especialidad SERIAL,
  nombre_especialidad VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_especialidad));
  
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                 TABLA JORNADA                      --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
   
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jornada (
  id_jornada  SERIAL,
  nombre_jornada VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  horario_jornada VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_jornada));
  
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                 TABLA INSTRUCTOR                   --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
 
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS instructor (
  fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  fk_numero_documento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  fk_id_vinculacion INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_especialidad INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_jornada INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento, fk_numero_documento),

    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento)
    REFERENCES usuario (fk_id_tipo_documento , numero_documento)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,

    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_vinculacion)
    REFERENCES vinculacion (id_vinculacion),

    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_especialidad)
    REFERENCES especialidad (id_especialidad),
  CONSTRAINT fk_instructor_jornada1
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_jornada)
    REFERENCES jornada (id_jornada)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
  CREATE INDEX fk_id_vinculacion_index ON instructor(fk_id_vinculacion ASC);
  CREATE INDEX fk_id_especialidade_index ON instructor(fk_id_especialidad ASC);
  

  
  
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                 TABLA TRIMESTRE                    --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
 
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trimestre (
  id_trimestre  SERIAL,
  numero_trimestres INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_trimestre));
  
  
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                 TABLA PROGRAMA                     --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS programa (
  id_programa SERIAL,
  siglas_programa VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  nombre_programa VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  fk_id_especialidad INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_programa, fk_id_especialidad),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_especialidad)
    REFERENCES especialidad (id_especialidad));  
    CREATE INDEX fk_id_especialidad_index ON programa(fk_id_especialidad ASC);
    
    
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                 TABLA COMPETENCIA                  --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             
             
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS competencia (
  id_competencia SERIAL,
  descripcion_competencia TEXT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_programa INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_especialidad INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_competencia, fk_id_programa, fk_id_especialidad),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_programa , fk_id_especialidad)
    REFERENCES programa (id_programa , fk_id_especialidad)); 
    CREATE INDEX fk_id_programa_especialidad_index ON competencia(fk_id_programa ASC, fk_id_especialidad ASC);
    
  
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                 TABLA RESULTADO_APRENDIZAJE        --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
  
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS resultado_aprendizaje (
  id_resultado_aprendizaje SERIAL,
  numero_resultado_aprendizaje INT NOT NULL,
  descripcion_resultado_aprendizaje TEXT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_competencia INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_programa INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_especialidad INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_resultado_aprendizaje, fk_id_competencia, fk_id_programa, fk_id_especialidad),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_competencia , fk_id_programa , fk_id_especialidad)
    REFERENCES competencia (id_competencia , fk_id_programa , fk_id_especialidad));
    CREATE INDEX fk_id_resApren_competencia_programa_especialidad_index ON resultado_aprendizaje(fk_id_competencia ASC, fk_id_programa ASC, fk_id_especialidad ASC);
    
  
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                 TABLA FICHA                     --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ficha (
  id_ficha SERIAL,
  numero_ficha INT NOT NULL,
  estado_ficha VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  fk_id_programa INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_especialidad INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_jornada INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_trimestre INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_competencia INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_ficha),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_programa , fk_id_especialidad)
    REFERENCES programa (id_programa , fk_id_especialidad),
 
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_jornada)
    REFERENCES jornada (id_jornada),

  
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_trimestre)
    REFERENCES trimestre (id_trimestre),
  
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_competencia)
    REFERENCES competencia (id_competencia));
    
     CREATE INDEX fk_id_programa_especialidad_index ON ficha(fk_id_programa ASC, fk_id_especialidad ASC);
     CREATE INDEX fk_id_jornada_index ON ficha(fk_id_jornada ASC);
     CREATE INDEX fk_id_trimestre_index ON ficha(fk_id_trimestre ASC);
     CREATE INDEX fk_id_competencia_index ON ficha(fk_id_competencia ASC);
  

  
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                 TABLA APRENDIZ_FICHA               --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aprendiz_ficha (
  fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  fk_numero_documento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  fk_id_ficha INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento, fk_numero_documento, fk_id_ficha),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento)
    REFERENCES aprendiz (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_ficha)
    REFERENCES ficha (id_ficha));
    
    CREATE INDEX fk_tipoDoc_numDoc_index ON aprendiz_ficha(fk_id_tipo_documento ASC, fk_numero_documento ASC);
    CREATE INDEX fk_id_ficha_index ON aprendiz_ficha(fk_id_ficha ASC);
    
    
  
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                 TABLA ADMINISTRATIVO               --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS administrativo (
  fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  fk_numero_documento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento, fk_numero_documento),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento)
    REFERENCES usuario (fk_id_tipo_documento , numero_documento));
    CREATE INDEX fk_id_tipoDocu_index ON administrativo(fk_id_tipo_documento ASC, fk_numero_documento ASC);
             
             
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                       TABLA POST                   --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post (
  id_post SERIAL,
  titulo_post VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  img_post TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  cuerpo_post TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  fecha_creacion DATETIME NOT NULL,
  fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  fk_numero_documento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_post, fk_id_tipo_documento, fk_numero_documento),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento)
    REFERENCES administrativo (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento));
    CREATE INDEX fk_id_tipoDoc_numDoc_index ON post(fk_id_tipo_documento ASC, fk_numero_documento ASC);
            
             
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                      TABLA LIKES                   --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS likes (
  id_like SERIAL,
  fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
  fk_id_post INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  fk_numero_documento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_like, fk_id_tipo_documento, fk_numero_documento),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_post)
    REFERENCES post (id_post),

    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento)
    REFERENCES usuario (fk_id_tipo_documento , numero_documento));
    
  CREATE INDEX fk_id_post_index ON likes (fk_id_post ASC);
  CREATE INDEX fk_id_id_tipDocum_numDoc_index ON  likes(fk_id_tipo_documento ASC, fk_numero_documento ASC);

         
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                 TABLA COMENTARIO                   --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comentario (
  id_comentario INT NOT NULL,
  comentario TEXT NOT NULL,
  fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
  fk_id_pos INT NOT NULL,
  usuario_numero_documento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  usuario_fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_comentario, usuario_numero_documento, usuario_fk_id_tipo_documento),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_post)
    REFERENCES post (id_post),
  CONSTRAINT fk_comentario_usuario1
    FOREIGN KEY (usuario_numero_documento , usuario_fk_id_tipo_documento)
    REFERENCES usuario (numero_documento , fk_id_tipo_documento)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
    
     CREATE INDEX fk_id_posti_index ON comentario(fk_id_post ASC);
     CREATE INDEX fk_id_comUser_index ON comentario(fk_comentario_usuario1_idx (usuario_numero_documento, usuario_fk_id_tipo_documento));
    
    
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                TABLA INSTRUCTOR_FICHA              --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS instructor_ficha (
  fk_id_ficha INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  fk_numero_documentO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (fk_id_ficha, fk_id_tipo_documento, fk_numero_documento),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_ficha)
    REFERENCES ficha (id_ficha),

    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento)
    REFERENCES instructor (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento));
    
    CREATE INDEX fk_id_ficha_index ON instructor_ficha(fk_id_ficha ASC);
    CREATE INDEX fk_id_tipDocum_numDoc_index ON instructor_ficha(fk_id_tipo_documento ASC, fk_numero_documento ASC);
    
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --                    TABLA PROYECTO                  -- 
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proyecto (
  id_proyecto SERIAL,
  nombre_proyecto VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  descripcion TEXT NOT NULL,
  etapa VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'lectiva',
  fk_id_programa INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_proyecto, fk_id_programa),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_programa)
    REFERENCES programa (id_programa));
    
     CREATE INDEX fk_id_programa_index ON proyecto(fk_id_programa ASC);

             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --               TABLA APRENDIZ_PROYECTO              --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aprendiz_proyecto (
  fk_id_proyecto SERIAL,
  fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  fk_numero_documento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (fk_id_proyecto, fk_id_tipo_documento, fk_numero_documento),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_proyecto)
    REFERENCES proyecto (id_proyecto),
 
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento)
    REFERENCES aprendiz (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento));
    
     CREATE INDEX fk_id_proyectos_index ON aprendiz_proyecto(fk_id_proyecto ASC);
     CREATE INDEX fk_id_numDocume_tipDoc ON aprendiz_proyecto(fk_id_tipo_documento ASC, fk_numero_documento ASC);
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --               TABLA INSTRUCTOR_PROYECTO            --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS instructor_proyecto(
  fk_id_proyecto  SERIAL,
  fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  fk_numero_documento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (fk_id_proyecto, fk_id_tipo_documento, fk_numero_documento),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_proyecto)
    REFERENCES royecto (id_proyecto),
  
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento)
    REFERENCES instructor (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento));
    
     CREATE INDEX fk_id_proyecto_index ON instructor_proyecto(fk_id_proyecto ASC);
     CREATE INDEX fk_id_tipDoc_numDoct_index ON instructor_proyecto(fk_id_tipo_documento ASC, fk_numero_documento ASC);
    
             -- -----------------------------------------------------
             --               TABLA COMPETENCIA_PROYECTO           --
             -- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS competencia_proyecto (
  id_competencia_proyecto SERIAL,
  estado_competencia_proyecto VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Por calificar',
  observacion_competencia TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  fk_id_proyecto INT NOT NULL,
  fk_id_tipo_documento INT NOT NULL,
  fk_numero_documento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_competencia_proyecto, fk_id_proyecto),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_proyecto)
    REFERENCES proyecto (id_proyecto),
  
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento)
    REFERENCES instructor_proyecto (fk_id_tipo_documento , fk_numero_documento));
    
     CREATE INDEX   fk_id_proyecto_index ON competencia_proyecto(fk_id_proyecto ASC);
     CREATE INDEX fk_id_tipdoc_numDoc_index ON competencia_proyecto(fk_id_tipo_documento ASC, fk_numero_documento ASC);
```

Solo hay dos tablas relacionadas con competencia, resultado_aprendizaje y ficha, pero no logro saber o determinar en qué lugar está el error o cual es el error en sí, por favor ayúdenme a identificar el error.

Según he investigado, el error se debe a que alguna referencia que usa la tabla competencia debe faltar, pero realmente no veo que falta.
Solo hay dos tablas relacionadas con competencia, resultado_aprendizaje y ficha, pero no logro saber o determinar en qué lugar está el error o cual es el error en sí, por favor ayúdenme a identificar el error.

Según he investigado, el error se debe a que alguna referencia que usa la tabla competencia debe faltar, pero realmente no veo que falta.
Solo hay dos tablas relacionadas con competencia, resultado_aprendizaje y ficha, pero no logro saber o determinar en qué lugar está el error o cual es el error en sí, por favor ayúdenme a identificar el error.

Según he investigado, el error se debe a que alguna referencia que usa la tabla competencia debe faltar, pero realmente no veo que falta.
Solo hay dos tablas relacionadas con competencia, resultado_aprendizaje y ficha, pero no logro saber o determinar en qué lugar está el error o cual es el error en sí, por favor ayúdenme a identificar el error.

Según he investigado, el error se debe a que alguna referencia que usa la tabla competencia debe faltar, pero realmente no veo que falta.

Comment: Según veo, la llave primaria de la tabla competencia está compuesta de 3 columnas. En cambio, cuando tratas de relacionar por ejemplo la tabla `Ficha`, solo referencias la columna `id_compentencia`. Eso no se puede hacer, se debe relacionar la llave completa

Comment: ¿Cómo debería quedar a tu modo de ver? Intenté la solución que me brindas, pero igualmente me tira el error, seguramente no lo estoy haciendo bien.